# I want to create Class diagram from the data already saved in database/datastore in java

Tags: java, html, jsp, google-app-engine

Basically it's a requirement modeling project, I have data of requirement already 
For example
I have data in database as

```
    Class Name= Users
    Variables= id, name, Address etc
    Methods= Sign In (), Sign Up () etc
```

I want to generate class diagram of this data at run time ( like when I click model requirement button then it should create the class diagram from this data )
Any plugin or API to do this ?  I am creating this project in JSP and Google App engine.
Any API or library that may take Data (Fetched from database ,Not the SOURCE CODE of my Project) and generate a class diagram from it on HTML file or any other format.

Thanks.

Some thing like this (more than 1 classes of course and links between them)

![image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khv3d.png

Comment: http://www.uml2.org/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/Eclipse_Database/Reverse_Existing_Database/index.html

Comment: use eUML2 plugin from Soyatec, " http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/com.soyatec.uml.doc/ " under Eclipse and it works fine for the generation of UML giving the source code.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I want to create it from just the data saved in database as shown in question.
Not from the source code of my project.

Comment: Use online tools..

Comment: I don't believe you can create *class* diagrams from just your database -- perhaps you mean an Entity-Relationship Diagram? For instance, you can use Workbench for MySQL to create such diagrams: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: for example? 
(how am I supposed to use online tools for this on my project in eclipse? data is in datastore of GAE.

Comment: @Crossdiver 
No I don't want ERD, I want class diagram ( the things that we need to create class diagram is stored in database or you can assume that I have the data in variables in java, the example of data is in the question.)
I want to create Class diagram from that data on run time, as mentioned in question.
Example Image is also there.